# Wamp document root is not updating

Tags: php, apache, localhost

Just finished installing WampServer 3.0.4. I want to set it up so when I visit http://localhost/, it serves the files within `e:/Archives/`, instead of the default WampServer page.

**Approach**

I found many answers that say I have to open `c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.18/conf/httpd.conf` and look for both the DocumentRoot and Directory lines (I found them around line 250). I substituted this:

```
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
    #...
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    #...
    AllowOverride all
    #   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require local
</Directory>
```

with this:

```
DocumentRoot "e:/Archives/"
<Directory "e:/Archives/">
    #...
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    #...
    AllowOverride all
    #   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require local
</Directory>
```

Notice the only two things updated were the Document Root and Directory paths.

**My problem**

Now, when I point my browser to `http://localhost`, it *still* shows the same default WampServer page in `C:\wamp\www\index.php`. Clicking on the `phpinfo()` link shows the following:

```
DOCUMENT_ROOT  C:/wamp/www
CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT C:/wamp/www
```

... which leads me to believe that my changes to httpd.conf aren't making any difference.

Has anybody ran into this issue? Is there a different way to change the default location that `localhost` points to? I've tried restarting WampServer, restarting my computer (Running Windows 7), etc.

Comment: Try adding a trailing `/` after `DocumentRoot` declaration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly try starting a new VirtualHost on localhost.

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
DocumentRoot "E:/Archives"
ServerName localhost
<Directory "E:/Archives">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    #   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Or, if that isn't the solution for you, and you are absolutely sure you changed any lines regarding `C:/wamp/www`, then you should try downgrading to WampServer 2. Usually that fixes most Apache problems.

**However, this is most likely happening because you didn't change the DocumentRoot at line 230 to** `DocumentRoot "e:/Archives"`

**Also, anything above Apache 2.4.9 doesn't work well, so I should downgrade to 2.5. Just so you know.**

Comment: Usually I just use a VirtualHost on localhost. Also, WampServer 2.5 can be found [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/Wampserver%202.5/)

Comment: Just updated it to what is probably the reason it isn't working.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I did change DocumentRoot to `e:/Archives` I updated my answer above to show more specifically what the httpd.conf document looks like to me now. Is there a way to change the variables within `phpinfo()` other than through httpd.conf?

Comment: Sorry, but that is the only way to change DocumentRoot. However, you could try putting a .htaccess file in C:/wamp/www with these lines. `DocumentRoot "E:/Archives"
<Directory "E:/Archives">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    #   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require all granted
</Directory>` However, I still recommend either downgrading Wamp using the link I sent in the comments, or creating a virtualhost. Tell me if that works.

Comment: Excellent! I downgraded from 3.0.4 to 2.5 where you linked me to, and now the changes on `httpd.conf` are being reflected. I wonder if it's a bug with the latest version? Thanks again!

Comment: This happens because anything above Apache 2.4.9 usually doesn't work as well. Also, lots of modules in Wamp 3 don't work and crash the server. So that's why I recommend sticking with good old Wamp 2. Glad I solved your problem! ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123380/discussion-between-gauched-and-marco-del-valle).

Answer (score 3):

Updating httpd.conf DocumentRoot does not work because there is a default virtual host created by WampServer automatically.

This can be found under:

C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

So either update this or create a second vhost.

Comment: Editing this file was the solution for me. For localhost, the document root was "${APPPATH}/www". Changed to the right path, restart services and it's done. Should be tagged as the best answer !